# How can I convert data returned by a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dcr_report_demo(
finid integer,
prdid integer,
comp_cd character varying,
divid integer,
fsid integer)
RETURNS refcursor
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
STR REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

OPEN STR FOR SELECT HD.REPORT_NO,HD.DCR_DATE,COALESCE( PR2.PARA_DESCR ,' 
') WORK_TYPE,
COALESCE( PR1.PARA_DESCR,' ') HQ_TYPE,COALESCE( RM.ROUTE_NAME,' ') 
ROUTE_NAME,
COALESCE(HD.DOCTOR_VISITS,0) DOCTOR_VISITS,COALESCE(HD.STOCKIST_VISITS,0) 
STOCKIST_VISITS,
COALESCE(HD.RETAILER_VISITS,0) 
RETAILER_VISITS,HD.DCR_ID,FM.FS_NAME,HD.FSTAFF_ID,
CASE HD.STATUS
WHEN 'A' THEN 'APPROVED'
WHEN 'D' THEN 'DISCARDED'
WHEN 'F' THEN 'FORWARDED'
WHEN 'E' THEN 'DRAFT' END STATUS ,ZSM.FS_NAME report1,
RSM.FS_NAME report2,FM.GEOG_LVL1_HQ,FM.LEVEL_CODE ,
COALESCE(PM.PARA_DESCR,'SELF') JOINT_WORK 
,FM.FS_CODE,FM.EMP_CODE,COALESCE(HD.DOC_OTHER,0) DOC_OTHER
FROM   DCRHD HD LEFT OUTER JOIN PARAMETERS PM ON HD.JFW = PM.PARA_CODE
AND PM.PARA_TYPE = 'JFW'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROUTE_MASTER RM ON RM.FSTAFF_ID=HD.FSTAFF_ID
AND RM.ROUTE_ID =HD.ROUTE_ID AND RM.COMPANY_CD = COMP_CD
LEFT OUTER JOIN parameters PR1 ON PR1.PARA_CODE  = HD.HQ_EXHQ
AND PR1.PARA_TYPE ='HQ_' ,parameters PR2,FIELD_MASTER FM,FIELD_MASTER 
ZSM,FIELD_MASTER RSM
WHERE HD.PERIOD_ID= PRDID AND HD.FIN_YEAR_ID= FINID
AND HD.FSTAFF_ID=FM.FS_ID
AND FM.MGR_LEVEL4=ZSM.FS_ID
AND FM.MGR_LEVEL3= RSM.FS_ID
AND FM.FS_ID=HD.FSTAFF_ID AND FM.LEVEL_CODE ='005'
AND PR2.PARA_CODE = HD.WORK_TYPE AND PR2.PARA_TYPE ='WTP' AND HD.COMPANY= 
COMP_CD
AND FM.COMPANY_CD = COMP_CD
ORDER BY FM.FS_NAME,DCR_DATE ;

RAISE NOTICE '%', STR ;
RETURN STR;
END;

$BODY$;
```

I am new to PostgreSQL. I have recently created a function here:

```
FINID
PRDID
COMP_CD
DIVID
```

FSID are my parameters which are passed to the function from the user. This function compiles successfully, but when I query `select * from dcr_report_demo(12,1,'VET',327,14);`, it says `<unnamed portal 1>`.

What could be the problem? How can I convert data returned by this function in PostgreSQL?

Comment: There's no reason to shout, it would help if you didn't post in all caps and if you formatted your block of code with indenting etc.

Comment: Also (1) why are you trying to print that refcursor in RAISE NOTICE and then (2) why are you calling it with "SELECT * FROM". You have read the section on cursors in the manual, haven't you? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: The fact is,Recently we running on oracle and decide to migrate to postgreSQL .Even though postgresql is almost identical to Oracle,For me it is a new world i have to start from the beginning..I got the procedure compiled but not got the desired output...would you help me if i share one of our procedure with you and would you suggest us the best way to convert it to postegresql model ???

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a refcursor as the return type and don't use a cursor inside the function.

All your function is doing is to return the result of a SQL query. That is best done with a `language sql` function that is declared as `returns table (...)`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dcr_report_demo(finid integer,
                                           prdid integer,
                                           comp_cd character varying,
                                           divid integer,
                                           fsid integer)
  RETURNS table(report_no integer, 
                dcr_date date, 
                work_type text, 
                hq_type text, 
                rout_name text, 
                .... rest of the columns ...) 
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $BODY$
  SELECT hd.report_no,
         hd.dcr_date,
         ... 
  FROM ...
    JOIN ...
  WHERE hd.period_id = prdid
    AND hd.fin_year_id = finid
    AND hd.company = comp_cd
    AND fm.company_cd = comp_cd
    .... 
  ORDER BY fm.fs_name,
           dcr_date;
$BODY$;
```

---

Unrelated: it's bad coding style to mix explicit JOIN operators and implicit joins in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you  for  the answer I will try your way, and would you  help me if i share one of our procedure( codded In oracle PLSQL)to  covert  to psotgreSQL??